pybricks turn causes the robot to spin forever
The following code is based on Spike Prime and Pybricks Beta.
The line that does the "turn" causes the robot to spin forever.
Adding the top side and front side arguments does not help.
Setting the drivebase "Settings" also does not help.
Using drivebase.drive(0,90) instead of turn stops the turning when the wheels are in the air for testing but causes the infinity spin when placed on the mat.
what could I be missing here?
from pybricks.hubs import PrimeHub
from pybricks.pupdevices import Motor
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Color, Button, Direction, Axis
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
from pybricks.tools import wait

hub = PrimeHub()

left_motor = Motor(port = Port.C, positive_direction=Direction.CLOCKWISE)
right_motor = Motor(port = Port.B, positive_direction=Direction.COUNTERCLOCKWISE)

drivebase = DriveBase(
        left_motor,right_motor,
        wheel_diameter=56,axle_track=128
    )


drivebase.use_gyro(True)

drivebase.straight(distance=250) 
drivebase.turn(angle=90)
drivebase.straight(distance=250) 
drivebase.turn(angle=90)


Is it possible your gyro is defective?  What happens if you turn the gyro off?

You seem to be right! Setting use_gyro to False functions better. Is the gyro built into the hub? Is there a workaround for this?

Hopefully not defective, but perhaps misconfigured?  There are optional parameters to PrimeHub() to specify how the hub is oriented relative to the robot body.  If yours is mounted upside-down (relative to the default), then the angular measurement is going to be meaningless.

Tried adding hub = PrimeHub(top_side = Axis.Z, front_side = Axis.X)  .... the display is on the top but the result is the same.
